# Is Dutch supported in System.Speech

Tags: c++, visual-studio, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

i'm working on a small project, and i'm quite stuck atm.

For this, I want my program to recognize Dutch language, but it does'nt seem to work. Everytime I insert the nl-NL in the recognition engine, it gives me the following error :

System.ArgumentException: No recognizer of the required ID found.

I know this error is related to the Dutch variant of the speech recognition because, when I use the english version it works just fine,

I installed the SDK's and dll's necessary, and yet, it doesn't seem to work.

so my question : 
Does anybody know how to make this work using the right Speech.dll's etc etc.

heres my code :
ps.
Its made in Visual studio

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
namespace Voice_Recognition
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SpeechRecognitionEngine recEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("nl-NL"));
    Int16 HelpCount;
    DateTime LastCallForHelp;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnEnable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        recEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        btnDisable.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void btnDisable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        recEngine.RecognizeAsyncStop();
        btnDisable.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Choices commands = new Choices();
        commands.Add(new string[] { "say hello", "print my name", "help", "ow" });
        GrammarBuilder gBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
        gBuilder.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("nl-NL");
        gBuilder.Append(commands);
        Grammar mygrammar = new Grammar(gBuilder);
        mygrammar.Name = "victors grammar";


        //recEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

        recEngine.LoadGrammar(mygrammar);
        recEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        recEngine.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(recEngine_SpeechRecognition);
    }

    public void recEngine_SpeechRecognition(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Form1.ControlCollection("label1").text = e.Result.Confidence;
        lblConfidence.Text = "" + e.Result.Confidence;

        if (e.Result.Confidence >= 0.65)
        {
            switch (e.Result.Text)
            {
                case "say hello":
                    lblAktie.Text = "Hello!";
                    break;
                case "print my name":
                    lblAktie.Text = "Your name is Victor";
                    break;
                case "help":
                    if (LastCallForHelp.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds < 5)
                    { HelpCount += 1; }
                    else
                    { HelpCount = 1; };
                    if (HelpCount > 3)
                    { lblAktie.Text = "Hulp wordt ingeschakeld"; }
                    else
                    { lblAktie.Text = "Roep nog eens een keer!" ; };
                    LastCallForHelp = DateTime.Now;
                    break;
                case "ow":
                    lblAktie.Text = "Waar doet het pijn?";
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The error message is quite explicit.  You'll have to use one of the supported languages.  Which is not Dutch.  Dat kan niet.

Comment: You're right, so it seems. But according to Microsoft it should be supported: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh378476%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: It talks about the Microsoft.Speech namespace.  Wrong version.